# Assigning pointer to string in c

Tags: c, pointers

```
char* get_string() {
char * a = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    a = "asdf";
    return a;
}
```

Can someone please explain why this function would cause memory leak?

Comment: Well, you called malloc, and you didn't call free..

Comment: but let's say I do want my function to return "asdf" how would I do it and avoid memory leak?

Answer (score 4):

You first initialized `a` with a pointer to a location in memory. Then you re-assign `a` to another pointer to location occupied by string `asdf`, so you lost the first pointer to the allocated memory. you can never free them since you lost track of the 5 bytes memory allocated by malloc initially.

You leak that 5 bytes of memory here.

If you want to copy `asdf` to the memory pointed by `a`, you can use `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(a, "asdf");
```

In this way, you need to call `free` in your code somewhere to avoid leaks.

Comment: How would you then assign anything to a? Is it by char * a = "asdf" without malloc?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

```
char * a = malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
```

you allocated memory here from the heap, a has an address in the heap (say `0x1234EEEE`) pointing into dynamic memory.  You need to free this allocation when done, else a memory leak happens.

then

```
a = "asdf";
```

now you have assigned a as pointing to static compile time memory location where the string `"asdf"` is stored (say `0x0BADBEEF`, it's not in the dynamic heap).  You no longer know where the hell you allocated memory from the malloc call above (it was at `0x1234EEEE`, but now you have no reference to it), therefore you can never free() it ... that's a leak;

Answer (score 0):

"char *a;"

a here is a pointer, it can point to anything.

"a = (char *)0x0000" 
should be valid, but not logical;

"long l = 12345L;
a = (char *)&l;"
this should be legal also, but not logical

"asdf" is a static string in your example, it is stored in compile time allocated memory. You can just "return("asdf");" from your function, understanding it is in a statically allocated memory space defined at compile time.  Working with pointers without understanding logical memory layouts will have ramifications you may soon learn ;~).

Comment: malloc(), calloc() and strdup() reserve memory out of the "heap", a dynamic memory pool, which becomes fragmented over time with successive allocations.  Static strings reside in different memory space that is contiguous,       

"char *a = "My String";
char *b= "Your String";"

end up in a static memory block as "My String\0Your String\0" that can never change size.  The pointers a and b can be later assigned to point anywhere, but don't try to move to / or change the place they pointed to on the original assignment ... big problem, probably protection violation.

disclaimer: 15 years retired